# Hystrix Javanica Timeouts taking longer than expected

Tags: java, hystrix

I'm running integration tests with the following property

`hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=1`

The tests do throw a timeout exception as expected, but only after they appear to have completed all executable code.

I expect the tests to complete in or around 1 millisecond, but they are taking 200-400 milliseconds (as they would without a timeout)

[image]